# Как правильно: «электролизер» или «электролизёр»?

Tags: орфография, е-или-ё

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, «электролизер» или «электролизёр»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: **электролизёр.**

Элетролизёр ― аппарат для электролиза. Описание его (с постановкой ударения) дается в энциклопедии:

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/153558/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%91%D1%80%D1%8B